# Split argument into an array and now getting an undefined in child scope

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined on line 5

when I enter this into the console. I'm not sure why it is saying `senArr[i]` is `undefined` when it's been split into an array and then passed into the for loop.

I've been trying to figure out why this error is showing up...

-the for loop does have access to the parent scope

-senArr is split into an array and I don't see any issue with taking the length of the strings stored in each index.

Out of ideas, I'm starting to think the issue is somewhere else in the code.

```
function LongestWord(sen) { 
    var senArr = sen.split(' ');
    var longestWord = senArr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i <= senArr.length; i++) {
       if (senArr[i].length > longestWord.length) {
           longestWord = senArr[i];   
       } 
    } return longestWord; 
}
```

Comment: `i` needs to start at 0, not 1. You're probably hitting an index that's out of bounds if you pass in a sentence that doesn't have any spaces in it anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, change your `<=` to `<` because the last index in the array is `senArr.length - 1`.

```js
function LongestWord(sen) {
  var senArr = sen.split(' ');
  var longestWord = senArr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < senArr.length; i++) {
    console.log('i is ', i, ' and word is ', senArr[i]);
    if (senArr[i].length > longestWord.length) {
      longestWord = senArr[i];
    }
  }
  return longestWord;
}

console.log(LongestWord('hi there this is a test'));
```

With `<=` you go beyond the last index (`i` becomes 6 in the above example) and there's no string at that index, which is why you see the error.

Comment: Isn't the first word in the array being skipped here since "let i = 1"  starts at the second element in the array?

Comment: @MarcM. `var longestWord = senArr[0];` initializes `longestWord` to the first word in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you compare to <= you include the array length+1 note that array is zero based index so the last item is length-1

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
var LongestWord = (sen) => { 
    var senArr = sen.split(' ');

    console.log(senArr);

    var longestWord = '';
    for (let i = 0; i <= senArr.length - 1; i++) {
       if (senArr[i].length > longestWord.length) {
           longestWord = senArr[i];   
       } 
    } return longestWord; 
}


console.log(LongestWord('alongword is the longest'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I just transformed this to modern javascript and it works :-)

```
function LongestWord(sentence) { 
    const words = sentence.split(' ');
    let longest = '';
    for (let word of words) {
        if (word.length > longest.length) {
            longest = word;
        } 
    } return longest; 
}

// notice that 'bar' is actually not the longest word
// but the first of all longest words
longestWord('fo bar baz'); // 'bar'
```